# How many methods are there to use React-Redux? Redux-thunk vs Redux-Saga?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am very confused with Redux as I am learning different methods.
I want to know how many more methods are there like `redux-Thunk`, `redux-saga`. All of them use a different function like CreateSlice. Which methods are suitable for small projects and what is the main difference between them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd recommend giving the official [Redux Style Guide](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide/) a read.

Generally: at this moment, there are 14818 redux-themed packages available on `npm`. It's pretty impossible to name them all ;)

But also, there are clear recommendations by the Redux team:

- use Redux Toolkit
- if you only need api data without further manual logic, use `createApi` form RTK-Query
- if you need manual logic attached to that, use `createAsyncThunk` or just [thunks](https://redux.js.org/usage/writing-logic-thunks). Only if those are not enough, turn to other middlewares like saga
- sagas are very overused, most of the time not needed and add unneccesary complexity. We are currently building an action-listener-middleware that covers about 75% of the saga functionality with a simpler api (those 25% functionality left after that are the *real* saga use case, but probably only 2-5% of users ever need those).
  That said, most people would not even need that and could probably do
  everything they are using sagas for with thunks instead, which are
  *much* more simple.

There are also other libraries like redux-observable etc. Those have a non-deniable market share in the single-digit percentages, but if you are just getting started, go by the official recommendations.

Best get started by reading [the official Redux Tutorial](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts). It should cover 90% of all the Redux knowledge you'll ever need.